# Drawable with multiple drawables below each other consecutively

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to make a drawable for the background of my RelativeLayout. I want to divide the RelativeLayout into 6 rectangles of equal size.

I would like to make 5 horizontal lines equal distance apart as a drawable so I can set it as the RelativeLayout background.

I've tried to do so with the following XML code:
drawable -

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/straight_line"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/straight_line"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/straight_line"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/straight_line"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/straight_line"/>
</layer-list>
```

straight_line.xml -

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid
        android:color="@android:color/white" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@android:color/black" />
</shape>
```

I'm new to xml so I can't tell why this isn't working. Any help is appreciated, thank you

Comment: Why You not use GridLayout? Sample:
[There](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39685524/12678078)

Comment: the reason why I'm not using gridlayout is because I'm planning on using this RelativeLayout to hold courses for a timetable. courses can be 1, 2, or even 3h long which makes the height of the view change and it wouldn't work well with GridLayout